# Merman Tom, pirate Hermione story

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Looking for an unfinished Tomione fanfic on [AO3](https://archiveofourown.org/).

Tom was a merman, the terror hiding in the depths, terrorizing honest sailors and pirates alike, sinking ships and drowning people in droves. Enter Hermione the pirate. Evil Ariel transitions into a dolphin and rescues Hermione from an untimely death in a watery grave.

Hermione is black, Tom has blue or grey scales.

Her ship was a schooner I think, not a sloop, it had a big crew. Don't remember who was the captain, but Harry was also on the ship.

The pirates also had a home port on an island with a friendly tavern owner, a former pirate.

No memory when I read it, more that a year, less than five.

No explicit sexual content, Hermione's POV, maybe third person, AU, less than 10K.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You might be able to improve this question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11922/101407) for asking fan-fic identification questions; if you remember any additional details, you can [edit] them into your question.

Comment: This is actually a pretty detailed question. Congrats on that! Forgive my ignorance, but is AOT a site? Could you spell it out? And this is Ariel as in the Little Mermaid?

Comment: Interesting. There should be enough information here to find it. I just want to clarify: which Tom? Tom Riddle, Tom the barkeep, or some other Tom from some other fiction, like Tom Bombadil? Also, merely out of curiosity, why does Ariel rescue Hermione if the former is evil?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I guess they mean Archive of Our Own? That's sometimes abbreviated AO3, which could easily be miswritten as AOT.

Comment: @Adamant I don't know :( i assumed it was Riddle, but who knows, maybe it was some other Tom.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yes, my mistake, it's AO3. And yes again. The story reminded me of Ariel the mermaid.

Comment: @CaptainKid Ah, so not necessarily Ariel, but an "evil mermaid" sort.

Comment: "The Pirate Princess" (https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10497761/1/The-Pirate-Princess) is the closest I've found so far, but no Tom, and only tangential mermaids.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots no, unfortunately that's not the story I am looking for, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

It's close enough for me to put forward as a potential answer, perhaps *[Pursuit](https://archiveofourown.org/works/10909119)* by quinault?

> “What are you?” Hermione hears herself asking, hating the slight tremble in her voice as she says it. She knows now she should not have wondered, she should not have leaned over the stern, her eyes following his pale body, the magnetic pull of his dark eyes, the unmistakeable glint of something below the surface of the water, something that almost looked like scales—
>
> “—a mortal once. But that was a long time ago. Now…I am a mere memory.” And his eyes actually glaze over with something close to sadness. “I am bound to these waters for eternity. It is a…difficult existence.”

Tom is a Siren, not a mermaid

> “It’s a…Fin? Like a mermaid?” He’d smiled at the juvenility of the remark.
>
> “‘Siren’ is the more appropriate term, if you wish to be exact.” She had tried to disguise her shock, unslackening her jaw and looking away with the shame of having been caught staring. But he knew she had been more affected than she let show—knew that his existence had introduced into her world ambiguity of a wholly different nature than what she was accustomed to. And yet, in spite of it all, he also knew her eyes drifted to the waves, searching for him in the depths.

Also, no dolphins other mermaid-type creatures, and the color of his scales are never stated.

Comment: it's a different fic, but thank you for your effort.